# how to add and commit for moving a file into a new directory?

Tags: git

I clone a git repository from a remote, where there is a file `test`.

In my local working tree, I create a new dir and move the file into the dir

```
mkdir dir1
mv test dir1
```

Then I add and commit:

```
git add *
git commit -m "another commit"
```

At last I push the commit to the remote repository:

```
git push origin master
```

On the remote, I find the remote repository still has `test` besides `dir1/test`, while my local one only has `dir1/test`. How can I make the file moving on remote as well? Thanks.

Comment: If you run git status locally you'll most likely see that the original test file is listed as being removed. This is what causes the file still being in the remote. The flow should also include you removing the file from git using `git rm test` after you moved it to the new location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use git mv instead of regular mv

Comment: thanks. (1) is `git add *` okay? It is often hard to specify all changed files. (2)  yes `git mv` works. but `git mkdir` doesn't. What commands for file/dir operations can be used after git and what can't?

Comment: git add * often adds more than you thought (like node_modules in a node.js project). I often use git commit -am "Commit message" to commit all changed files that are tracked (but doesn't add any untracked files). If you want to add new files you can specify a partial path: git add dir1 (adds all files and subdirectories in dir1)

Comment: What do you use instead of `git add *`?

Comment: git add partialpath (as described above)

Comment: git add does not remove file - only add them. Use `git add -A .` to stage also removed files.

Comment: You're right, I didn't read properly. Although I like git rm better for that.

Answer (score 2):

Use `git status` more often. Especially before `git commit`. It tells you what to do to achieve your goals.

In your case it would tell you to run:

```
git rm test
```

in order to add the removal of the file `test` into the next commit. `git add *` added to the index only the presence of the file `test` on its new location (making it a copy instead of a move).